# Kivy using kv file. Gridlayout size hints not working

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

As the heading suggests, the FileChooserListView is taking up the whole Grid, not just 50%.

```
class MediaSorterScreen(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MediaSorterScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Builder.load_file('MediaSorter.kv')

class MediaSorter(App):
    def build(self):
        return MediaSorterScreen()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MediaSorter().run()
```

MediaSorter.kv

```
<MediaSorterScreen>:

    GridLayout:
        cols:2
        size: root.width - 200, root.height -200
        pos: 100, 100

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: (0.5, 1.0)

            FileChooserListView:
                id: srcFolderInput
                path: 'D:\\Daniel'
                size_hint: (1.0, 1.0)
```

Expecting FileChooserListView to take up 100% of BoxLayout which should take up 50% of the width of GridLayout, but FileChooserListView taking up 100% of GridLayout

Answer (score 0):

The basic calculation of row and column sizes are discussed in the [GridLayout documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.gridlayout.html#column-width-and-row-height). However, some details are not clearly specified. If all the Widgets in a column have a defined `width` (like `size_bint_x: None` and `width: 50`), then that column will have a width of `50`. Any columns where the Widgets have values for `size_hint_x` will get a share of the remaining `GridLayout` `width` proportional to that `size_hint_x`. So, continuing the same example, if the Widgets in the remaining columns all have `size_hint_x: 0.837`, they will all share equally in the remaining width. In the `GridLayout`, the actual value of `size_hint_x` is not important, only its relative value matters.

So, in your case, you have a `GridLayout` with 2 columns, but there is nothing in the second column. The second column gets assigned a width of 0, and the first column then shares the remaining width (the entire width) with no other column, so it gets the full width of the GridLayout regardless of the value of `size_hint_x`.

The fix is to provide something in the second column to claim a share of the width. Something like:

```
<MediaSorterScreen>:

    GridLayout:
        cols:2
        size: root.width - 200, root.height -200
        pos: 100, 100

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: (0.5, 1.0)

            FileChooserListView:
                id: srcFolderInput
                path: 'D:\\Daniel'
        Widget:
            size_hint: (0.5, 1.0)
```

And, unless you are planning to add more Widgets to the `BoxLayout`, you can eliminate that:

```
<MediaSorterScreen>:

    GridLayout:
        cols:2
        size: root.width - 200, root.height -200
        pos: 100, 100

        FileChooserListView:
            id: srcFolderInput
            path: 'D:\\Daniel'
            size_hint: (0.5, 1.0)
        Widget:
            size_hint: (0.5, 1.0)
```

Note that both of the above `kv` files should produce a warning:

> [WARNING] <**main**.MediaSorterScreen object at 0x7fd02d1c3ca0> have
> no cols or rows set, layout is not triggered.

Because the `MediaSorterScreen` is a `GridLayout` and should have `cols` or `rows` set.

And going even further, since the `MediaSorterScreen` is itself a `GridLayout`, you don't need another `GridLayout` inside it:

```
<MediaSorterScreen>:
    cols:2
    size_hint: .8, .8
    pos_hint: {'x': 0.1, 'y': 0.1}

    FileChooserListView:
        id: srcFolderInput
        path: 'D:\\Daniel'
        size_hint: (0.5, 1.0)
    Widget:
        size_hint: (0.5, 1.0)
```